# What term includes words and parts of words?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single term which includes words and parts of words, e.g., the term could be applied to any of these:

- the word “international”
- the root “inter-” taken independently of the words it fits in
- any segmentable part of a word, e.g. “in”, “ter”, “na”, “tion”, “al”, which is in this case segmentation by syllable

The term could, but need not necessarily, include letters.

Comment: All of those things are *substrings* of the word, though not all substrings are categories on their own, like *prefixes* or *syllables* are. Do you want something that encompasses only the categorized parts of a word?

Comment: -1 research not shown

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on whether the word chunk is a meaningful constituent or not. Most chunks aren't.

In *international*, there are at least three ***[Morphemes](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAMorpheme.htm)*** -- maybe four, depending on whether one counts the **in-** in *inter*:

- **in-ter . nation . al**

Morphemes are the meaningful chunks of words, like **book** and **keep** in ***bookkeepers***, as well as [derivational and inflectional](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) bound forms like **-al**, **-er**, and **-s**.

However, meaningless substrings such as *terna, ookkee,* or *nal* are not morphemes.